# Validate a form at the client side

Tags: javascript

I wish to validate a form at the client side (before submit to server). I have a script to search for special characters (~!@#) etc. If at least one exists, form should not be submitted until the user corrects the error(s). Here is my form:

```
<form  id="setUp" method="post" action="Usercontact.php">
<table id="contact">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Name of user:</td>
<td><input type="text" name='username' required /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Course</td>
<td><input type="text" name='useraddy1' required  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Telephone</td>
<td><input type="text" name='userfone' required  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">e-mail Address</td>
<td><input type="email" name='schemail' required  /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input id="postform" type="submit" onclick="err()" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

Below is the script

```
<script>
function err() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("contact");
    var name = tbl.rows[0].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var addy = tbl.rows[1].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var fone = tbl.rows[2].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
    var email = tbl.rows[3].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

    var namepos = name.lastIndexOf("~`!@#$%^&*)(+=}{][|\:;'.'/"',>?<");
    var addypos = addy.lastIndexOf("~`!@#$%^&*)(+=}{][|\:;'.'/"',>?<");
    var fonepos = fone.lastIndexOf("~`!@#$%^&*)(+=}{][|\:;'.'/"',>?<");
    var emailpos = name.lastIndexOf("~`!@#$%^&*)(+=}{][|\:;'.'/"',>?<");

    if (namepos !== -1 || addypos !== -1 || fonepos !== -1 || emailpos !== 
    -1) {
        document.getElementById("postform").addEventListener("click",  
        function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Please why is this script not working. The form is submitted even when there are special characters in any of the input fields. Appreciate

Comment: Off-topic, but since you're using the same `indexOf()` call using the same regular expression multiple times, you really should make that a function, rather than repeat yourself. Remember: keep [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: use `onsubmit` instead of `onclick`

Comment: Have you had a look at using the pattern attribute for HTML 5 - not support buy Safari but its something to look at as well - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: tbl.rows[0].cells[1].getElementsByTagName  - I would change code to get elements by ID instead of table row position. Otherwise you need to change your JS code everytime new row is added to HTML table or designer changes page layout

Comment: @David Thomas You are right. Wont forget your advise.

Comment: @Artyom Neustroev Many txs. I wonder why I missed out this page as I am using w3schools. This approach is the best, easy & clear. I applied it & it works.The form is not submitted until every error is cleared.

Comment: @Maksym Kozlenko Txs for this tip which I have applied successfully

Comment: @OluAdabonyan glad it helped! Please, see [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com) about w3schools

Comment: @ Artyom Neustroev Txs for the tip. Wot site will you recommend for PHP, SQL, MySQLi

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
var namepos = name.lastIndexOf("~`!@#$%^&*)(+=}{][|\:;'.'/"',>?<");
```

is checking for the entire string ("~`!@#$%^&*)(+=}{][|:;'.'/"',>?<"), not each character.

As suggested in the comments, you could use the HTML5 pattern attribute:

```
<input name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,12}">
```

This would require the name to include only letters and range in length from 3 to 12 characters.

To use a regular expression to test for all the characters you listed, you could use:

```
var re=/[~`!@#$%^&*)(+=}{\]\[|\:;'.'\"',>?<]/
var str="this@that";

if (re.test(str)) {
    console.log('The string has one of the characters');
} else {
    console.log('The string does not have any of the characters');
}
```

Comment: Even if you're not going for the pattern method, it's always best to specify what characters you want to accept instead of what you want to refuse.

Comment: @user2182349 and Jacque Goupil txs for your input. I have applied yours with others above and have now a working doc. I have reproduced below the new doc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include event. PreventDefault()..  This will prevent the form from submitting if you find characters you are checking for or anything else you might be checking for.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions above, I have now a working doc as follows:

```
<form  id="setUp" method="post" action="Usercontact.php">
<table id="contact">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Name of user:</td>
<td><input type="text" name='username' required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9.-_]
{5,12}"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Course</td>
<td><input type="text" name='useraddy1' required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{5,15}" 
/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">Telephone</td>
<td><input type="text" name='userfone' required pattern="[0-9.-_]{6,15}" />     
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="cdtl">e-mail Address</td>
<td><input type="email" name='schemail' required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9.-_@]" 
/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<br>
<input id='submit' type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

The script was removed as there is no need for it.